# How to understand the description of 'static field' in the Evaluation Order section of MDN's Classes?

Tags: javascript

[image]
At first, this was my understanding.

```js
class MyClass {
  static staticMethod() {}
}
console.log(MyClass.staticMethod); // At this point, this is set to the class itself, and then the evaluation proceeds.
```

But...

```js
class MyClass {
  static staticMethod() {}
}
console.dir(MyClass); // MyClass includes staticMethod.
```

From this code, I noticed that even if MyClass.staticMethod is not executed, the static field initializer is still evaluated. Why is that? Is it because this is already set to the class itself during the class definition, and then the evaluation takes place?

Comment: Why would you expect the static method to be executed? There's no call of it anywhere. The "evaluation order of classes" refers to when the method itself is **created** on the class.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, I don't understand the meaning of the phrase 'its initializer is evaluated with this set to the class itself,' and I'm curious about when 'this' is set to the class itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a static *field*, your example contains a static method. A [static class field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) looks like this:

```
class MyClass {
  static someField = 42;
}
```

The "initialiser" that gets evaluated during the class creation is the expression that the field is initialised with, `42` in the above example.

You can test the evaluation order that the text in your screenshot talks about with this code:

```js
console.log("before class");
class Example {
  static { console.log("static initialisation block 1"); }
  static field = console.log("static field", this);
  static { console.log("static initialisation block 2"); }
}
console.log("after class");
```

This initialises `Example.field` with `undefined`, but logs a message and the incomplete class in doing so.

Comment: Can I understand it this way? The initializer of a static field is evaluated at the time of class definition. The this keyword inside the initializer expression static someField = 42; refers to the class itself.

Comment: @desenzhao yes.